# Access ASP control from static method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I can't achieve this one:

I have a dynamically-generated table in HTML. One of the columns contains just links, it's a column that contains  tags. So every link has assigned a function that makes an ajax call and communicates with an aspx:

```
function cargaDatosModificacion(id) {
    var dto = {};
    dto.idPromoBanco = id;

    var dtoJSON = JSON.stringify(dto);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'PromosBancos.aspx/CargaDatosModificacion',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: dtoJSON,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: errorResponse
    });

}
```

So as you can see, the function receives an ID an calls 'PromosBancos.aspx/CargarDatosModificacion' via ajax.

Well, that aspx contains some ASP controls, like textbox and stuff.
When I try to 'do the stuff' with that controls, I notice that I don't have access to them. So yes, it's the 'static' clause.
Obviously when I get rid of the 'static' keyword, I won't be able to make the ajax call work.

I tried making every control static, didn't work either.

So I'm in the middle of this trouble, and the question is: **Is there ANY chance that I can access to the ASP Controls from a static method?**

Or: **Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? (access ASP controls after clicking on a HTML element).**

Comment: You can't do that; the entire page lifecycle does not run.

Comment: That means I'll have to use the GridView control, I guess...

Comment: You can access your Asp.Net controls by your ID using JQuery.